# @ManyToOne is generating as "not null" and should be nullable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In a Spring Boot Microservice, I have an Entity with this @ManyToOne relationship:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "VALIDATION_CURRNT_STATUS", nullable = true)
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
private ProcessStatusRfrnc validationStatus;
```

Note that the "optional = true" and "nullable = true" in the @ManyToOne and the @JoinColumn are redundant as those are the defaults, but I set them to try to resolve this issue.   When I run unit tests, I am seeing the Create Table for this entity generating like this:

```
 validation_currnt_status SMALLINT UNSIGNED not null
```

This seems wrong but I can't figure out why it is generating as "not null", it should be nullable.

Comment: Still not sure what is causing this behavior.  Seems like a hibernate bug?  Nobody else experiencing this?